# ng-click e ng-dblclick no mesmo elemento

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div ng-click = "clickOne()" ng-dblclick = "clickTwo()">Enter</div>
```

JavaScript>

```
$scope.clickOnce = function () {    
  alert("CLick One");    
}

$scope.clicktwice= function () {    
 alert("CLick two");    
}
```

Teria alguns jeito do meu ng-click não interferir no meu ng-dblclick. ao clicar uma vez esperar um tempo antes de executar a função, para diferenciar o ng-dblclick do ng-click, pois agora mesmo eu clicando duas vezes ele aciona a minha função de um click.

Comment: Segue um exemplo solucionando este problema, o usuário criou uma especie de contador de clicks. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444409/handling-ng-click-and-ng-dblclick-on-the-same-element-with-angularjs][1]